# providing multiple variables as data within a package

Tags: r, package

I have 4 changing data frames, depending on the experiment I am working on and I wand to provide several example experiments together with my package, but I am not sure how to add the data into my package, since in the manual it says only one data frame per data set.

So for example my 4 standard data frames are called `pg`, `summary`, `peptides` and `parameters`. I saved them within one `.RData` file.

```
save(summary, parameters, pg, peptides, file='trible-label.RData')
```

I also created the other data frames and saved a second data set with

```
save(summary, parameters, pg, peptides, file='double-label.RData')
```

I moved those data sets into the `data/.` folder of my package and want to document them now, but since it is not just one data frame, I am not sure how this should work or if it is the best way of doing so.

I thought about putting everything into a list and using this list as the dataset, but all my examples using the direct variables.

Has anyone a better solution?

Comment: Would putting everything into a list and preceding your examples with an otherwise advised against `attach` work for you?

Comment: I always have the feeling I am doing something wrong, when I attach things into my environment, but if there is no better solution, I would prefer it before creating each variable separately with differing names.

Comment: What about saving them individually, as 'summary.double', 'summary.trible', etc etc. Then create a function `load_data <- function(experiment=c("double", "trible"))` where you load the appropriate files and rename them to only 'summary'?